# Main differences of Karate & Taekwondo

Tags: tae-kwon-do, karate, style

I'm asking b/c, to an outsider, they can appear similar.  But, clearly, there are key distinctions.

- What are the distinctions between Karate and Taekwondo

A good answer should touch on similarities, distinctions, focuses, philosophy, and what each art is optimized for.

Answer (score 11):

I won't get too academic about it, so I'll give you the layman's summary.

And for the purpose of comparison, I'll emphasize the difference between Shotokan karate and Taekwondo, since Taekwondo derives from Shotokan directly. The differences increase greatly if you're talking about all of karate vs. Taekwondo. There are just too many branches of karate to really do that kind of a comparison well.

During the Japanese occupation of Korea (1910-1945), Koreans were forbidden to practice traditional Korean martial arts. The Japanese drafted young Korean men into the Japanese military. In Japan, these Korean soldiers - most of whom had no prior training in martial arts - would be exposed to Japanese martial arts such as Shotokan Karate, Daito Ryu Aikijujitsu, Judo, classical Jujitsu, and Kendo.

After the occupation ended, there was lingering resentment and anger towards the Japanese by the Koreans. They wanted to remove all aspects of Japanese culture from Korea and restore Korea's culture to the pre-occupation days.

The only problem was that 35 years was a long time. That meant 2 whole generations of people grew up in Korea never having been exposed to pre-occupation Korean culture. You can't bring something back if nobody remembers what that something was.

The martial arts, in particular, were suppressed to such a high degree in Korea that only a handful of older people carried on the traditions in secret. And they were old. Most who remembered it didn't really want to teach it or didn't feel they had sufficiently remembered it. Whole styles just vanished forever. Today, older Korean martial arts such as Taekkyon barely exist, and what is there is likely incomplete. Some of these styles were restored based only on photos, drawings, and oral history.

The Koreans were feeling understandably dejected. In order to restore pride to Korea, there was a push to come up with a national Korean martial art and sport that could rally everyone together. Without traditional Korean martial arts teachers to teach the new post-occupation Korea, the Korean martial artists that returned from Japan did what any good Korean would do: They Koreanized their Japanese martial arts and pretended or made it appear that they were Korean in origin. They simply couldn't call them Japanese martial arts, because the Koreans hated anything associated with the Japanese.

Taekwondo came from Shotokan karate and would become the national sport and martial art of Korea.

Hapkido came from Daito Ryu Aikijujitsu. Yudo came from Judo. Kumdo came from Kendo. These styles haven't achieved the popularity and significance that Taekwondo has for the Korean people.

Most schools of Taekwondo no longer practice the original Shotokan karate forms, although you can still find it in a few schools. ITF Taekwondo was the first federation of Taekwondo, and most of its forms were created by General Choi Hong Hi and contemporaries. These forms were the first generation of non-Japanese Taekwondo forms. They had names like "chon-ji", "dan-gun", "do-san", and so on.

These ITF forms were affectionately referred to as "blender forms", because they just took the original Shotokan karate kata, jumbled them up in a blender, and pulled out seemingly random moves to place in the new Taekwondo form. Actually, it was more complicated than that and definitely not random. But you get the idea. Typically, you might see 3 movements strung together in a Taekwondo form that came from a Shotokan karate form in the same order. So they weren't completely random, in other words. And probably the original authors of those Taekwondo forms thought those movements had some significance in order to keep them together like that.

Later, WTF Taekwondo would break off from ITF to form its own federation. And in doing so, they took those first generation ITF forms and attempted to Koreanize them even further. These second generation forms were named "taeguk 1", "taeguk 2", etc. These forms had higher kicks and more of them. In addition, the forms appear to have been constructed based on a cohesive philosophy separate from what they perceived as the original Shotokan karate philosophy. But that's a separate discussion.

And there have been many other Taekwondo federations and organizations breaking off from both ITF and WTF. Literally there have been thousands. These gave rise to the McDojo phenomenon of the 1980's. It seemed everyone was an 8th, 9th, or 10th degree black belt in their own style. Each one inventing their own forms.

Taekwondo comes directly from Shotokan karate. And Shotokan karate comes directly from Okinawan Shorin Ryu karate. Okinawan karate practices kata bunkai, which is a self-defense analysis for all of the kata in karate. In short, the karate kata encapsulate stand-up grappling based self-defense techniques for common everyday scenarios that are still applicable today. It's basically similar to classical jujitsu, with bone breaking added. The blocks in these forms aren't really blocks. You don't learn how to block by doing solo forms. You learn blocking from sparring. You learn self-defense grappling from kata.

Whereas, Shotokan karate does not practice bunkai, and so this self-defense meaning of the kata was not transmitted to Shotokan karate. And if it wasn't transmitted to Shotokan, it definitely wasn't transmitted to Taekwondo.

So the forms in Taekwondo (and to a large degree, Shotokan also) are basically meaningless. That allowed people to create new forms however they wanted. It's all pretty worthless as far as self-defense is concerned. But it is cool to practice for its own sake. It gives practitioners a challenge and a sense of growth when they learn and perfect new forms. In many ways, it's similar to contemporary wushu in that respect.

ITF and WTF Taekwondo differ in lots of other ways besides forms. In sparring, WTF has rules which forbid excessive force and punching to the face. People in WTF tournaments wear a lot more protective gear, too. Whereas in ITF, punching to the face is allowed, and harder contact is allowed. You can knock someone out in ITF, but it's not allowed in WTF. There's less protective gear in ITF.

There's much greater emphasis on defense in ITF than in WTF. In WTF, blocking is considered a waste of energy, which is why you often will see WTF fighters with their hands permanently down. In WTF, getting points wins, and you don't get points by blocking. So their strategy is to always be on the attack and be aggressive. In ITF, the motivation for blocking is to not get hurt (harder contact, and punches to the face are allowed). And so most people see ITF as more practical and realistic when compared with WTF.

Both ITF and WTF do continuous sparring, where nobody stops the fight when a point is scored. In addition to continuous sparring, there's also 3-point sparring, which is more popular in ITF schools. In 3-point sparring, the first one to reach 3 points wins. After scoring a point, the action is stopped and both players are centered up again. This 3-point sparring emphasizes defense, strategy (seeing patterns and predicting an opponent's next move), and split second timing / accuracy to a much greater degree than continuous sparring does. That's because you can only allow your opponent to hit you 3 times before you lose, so you have to play a more defensive game. And because the motion is stopped and players are returned to the center, it gives them the ability to focus and read their opponent. Whereas in continuous sparring, you can risk more to gain more points, and there is less time to think and focus on timing and strategy.

As for Shotokan karate, sparring is more like ITF Taekwondo's continuous sparring. There's less emphasis on protective gear. Punching and kicking to the face is allowed, although KO's and excessive force can cause disqualification in most cases. Shotokan also allows for punches to a downed opponent, something Taekwondo does not permit. And Shotokan allows for throws and sweeps, something that Taekwondo also does not permit. There's a lot greater emphasis on "cleaner" execution in order to get a point in Shotokan than in Taekwondo as well.

As for stances, Taekwondo in general has a much higher stance than Shotokan karate does. The center of gravity in a Taekwondo practitioner is much higher and tends to bob up and down. It's because it's much easier to perform high, snappy kicks that way. And you're more mobile with shorter, higher stances.

Whereas, in Shotokan karate, the center of gravity is low (at the hara / tanden / dantien), and stays there throughout. That is due in part to the greater emphasis on keeping balanced and preventing falls. Shotokan has deeper and longer stances than the Okinawan karate it came from. That's because of Shotokan's emphasis on physical fitness and away from practical self-defense. (Shotokan was brought to Japan by Gichin Funakoshi who adapted it for use in Japan's physical education programs for school children.)

Also, if you look at the level of the top of the head of a Taekwondo practitioner and trace it out, you'll see it goes up and down, especially for people doing ITF Taekwondo (which bases its movement on "sine wave" theory). Whereas in Shotokan, the head stays at the same level throughout. Power generation in Shotokan focuses more on the hips, rooted in a deep stance. Whereas, power generation in Taekwondo is more dynamic and depends on motion.

In terms of physical fitness, both Shotokan karate and Taekwondo will give you a good workout. But Taekwondo tends to be much more athletic. The emphasis in Taekwondo is on cardio stamina. There's a lot more movement in class. Whereas there is more emphasis in Shotokan karate on focus and meditation.

In terms of power, Taekwondo develops powerful kicks, but its punches are often much less developed. In Shotokan karate, it's the reverse: punching power is emphasized. Although, you could say that it's much more balanced for Shotokan karate than for Taekwondo.

There's a lot more to this topic, obviously. But I'll wrap it up here.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Wow.  Thanks for this answer.  I especially appreciate the detail on  kata bunkai, but the level of detail in general answered a lot of other questions, in terms of practice and theory.

Comment: TLDR: read the last paragraph beginning "In terms of power..."

Comment: Would be helpful to include a section on board/brick breaking, which is a big part of ITF to practice power and precision. Is it also a part of karate?

Comment: For reference, the Tae Kwon Do in the olympics is under WTF rules.

Comment: Minor point.  "*Shotokan karate does not practice bunkai*" Modern Shotokan certainly does, and I believe it did in the early 20th century too. The point is more that Shotokan's basic bunkai are aimed at a philosophy of blocks being to defend against punches and kicks, and it isn't until further down the line that you discover the alternative uses.  (Although even then, the basic bunkai for Heian Shodan have to include the third rising block being a forearm strike to the jaw/neck, otherwise it makes no sense because you've turned your back on an attacker without putting them down.)

Comment: Every "bunkai" I have ever seen from Shotokan is based on a flawed understanding of what the original Okinawan karate kata were about. Funakoshi-sensei did not teach Bunkai. His Shotokan karate was adapted for school children to use in Japanese physical education programs. The self-defense aspects were not taught and left up to the students' imaginations. The only thing they knew was striking and blocking, and so that's what they imagined the kata were about. If Shotokan is attempting to bring true bunkai back, that's great! But it requires returning to their Okinawan karate roots.

Comment: Board breaking is done in Shotokan and in Taekwondo. Both do it for the same reasons. It is more common to see it in Taekwondo demonstrations, though. And it's more common for Taekwondo to use boards that are very brittle and easy to break.

Comment: @SteveWeigand - Just a minor quibble - Many modern schools of all types use the plastic rebreakable boards. I find them to be more difficult than their "equivalent" board rating than regular boards when new, to absurdly easy as they get late in their use life. It's mostly a cost and a mess factor.

Comment: @JohnP & Steve Wiegand Are there forms of katas which involve useful combinations?  (In wudang the form practice is central for training the body to generate power and movement from the waist, sinking of the joints, & expanding/contracting the chest/upper back.  But individual movements have multiple applications, and there are sequences of movements that are highly practical.  For instance, a very quick front kick meant to lure an opponent into rushing in, followed by a finishing move such as "taming the tiger" which is a set of counters then simultaneous temple/kidney strike from inside.)

Comment: Yes, all Okinawan karate styles generally practice kata bunkai. You can look it up on youtube. Bunkai will break down the movements of the kata into their practical self-defense application. These aren't made for sparring or fighting. They're made for self-defense. There's a difference.

Comment: @DukeZhou - Yes, although almost all kata is highly stylized, you can take segments as self defense. That's one of my instructors favorite things to do is break down parts of our forms into practical self defense. You generally have to modify them somewhat, but it gives a much better sense of the purpose behind the prescribed moves.

Comment: @JohnP I come from what was originally a fighting lineage, although my teacher switched to gentle later in life.  But the forms are there to maintain the techniques validated by that last generation of life-of-death fighters, which are ideally researched and refined further, and re-validated with each generation.  (Some things are discarded, some added, some aspects emphasized, some de-emphasized.)  Am I correct that this is also the karate tradition in regard to self defense application?

Comment: The idea that the forms are based on movements that were used successfully in fights/battle is very common. But it's more like: So-n-so master made this form after meditating, or watching some animal, etc. Much of what is in traditional martial arts is conceptual. Ie, theory. It may have worked in some cases, but that's not a high bar. You need to start with theory and then test. Then modify based on the test results. Don't assume anything doesn't need testing or is too precious to discard. What each gen says is valid is filtered through their own beliefs and understanding, not often tested.

Comment: @DukeZhou - Also what Steve W said. Forms anymore in the majority of styles are to learn and reinforce the learning of the techniques being taught in the class. Can the sequences be used in self defense? Sure, but that really isn't the purpose behind the form. That's what in class sparring, fighting and ground fighting is for.

Comment: @SteveWeigand Good point.  (Although this is not about tai chi, that art is widely misunderstood as a set of forms and application, as opposed to a method of movement, often referred to as "technique".)  Always important to test and validate, thus my interest in the methods of karate training.  I personally find old-school karate (not kickboxing style) to be more formidable than most other martial arts b/c the kicks and punches are so rooted and powerful, and it's so no-nonsense.  Versatility is great, but there's much to be said for focusing on a small number of "bread&butter" techniques.

Comment: My instructor once quoted his instructor (Chen Qingzhou) on the subject of Taiji forms: "The movements in the form just give you something martial to do while practicing the internal mechanics." To some, the forms are everything. To others, they're just something to do which will get you further, but they're not the end.

Answer (score -4):

اصلی ترین تفاوت آنها در زدن ضربات پای آنهاست.
بطور کلی یک تکواندوکار در زدن ضربه پا لگن پای خود،را روبداخل،اما کاراته کاردرضربه پا، لگن پایش رو به بیرون می‌باشد واین برای یک تکواندوکار پوئن بزرگیست چون از فاصلهٔ دورتری برحریفش مسلط می‌‌شود
بعنوان مثال،یته پرنده یا تیپ یوپ چاگی درتکواندو بسیار از کاراته قویتر وموثرتر میباشد!

Translation:

> The main difference between them is their kicks.
> In general, a taekwondo fighter kicks his pelvis in the kick, but karate kicks his pelvis outwards at the foot of the foot, and this is a big point for a taekwondo fighter because he dominates his opponent from a distance, for example, a flying yet or a very *yup chap*. It is stronger and more effective than karate

[image: Image of a person doing a flying kick with the text of "Arash"]